# R shiny selectInput: how to search group name/label

Tags: r, shiny

I have made a shiny selectInput with groups and have been struggling to make it possible for a user to also search the name of the group rather than only having to search for a specific code in the group.

[image]

Here is the reproducible code:

```
icd <- tibble(ICD10=c("C00","C01","C01","C02","C03","C03"), 
          Description=c("Malignant neoplasm of lip","Malignant neoplasm of lip","Malignant neoplasm of base of tongue",
                        "Malignant neoplasm of other and unspecified parts of tongue","Malignant neoplasm of gum","Malignant neoplasm of gum"),
          Extended=c("C00.0","C00.1","C01","C02","C03.0","C03.1"),
          Labels = c("External upper lip","External lower lip","Malignant neoplasm of base of tongue",
                     "Border of tongue","Upper gum","Lower gum"))

icd$Description <- as.factor(as.character(icd$Description))
icd$Extended <- as.factor(as.character(icd$Extended))

cicd <- split(as.list(levels(icd$Extended)), icd$Description)

ui <- navbarPage(
title="Multiple Select",
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(uiOutput("var1_select")),
mainPanel()
))

server <- function(input, output) {
output$var1_select <- renderUI({
selectInput(
  "ind_var_select",
  "Select Names", 
  choices = cicd,
  multiple = TRUE
 )
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You might take a look at https://github.com/CVIRU/shiny.icd which has a relatively sophisticated shiny interface to ICD codes, and may help you in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying several other options, the only solution seems to be to use 'selectizeInput'.

```
icd$Description <- as.factor(as.character(icd$Description))

x <- as.vector(levels(icd$Description))

groups <- function(x){
for(i in 1:length(x)){
if(i == 1){
  savelist <-c()
  newlist <- list(list(value = x[i], label=x[i]))
  savelist <- c(savelist, newlist) 
}else{
  newlist <- list(list(value = x[i], label=x[i]))
  savelist <- c(savelist, newlist) 
 }
}
 return(savelist)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
selectizeInput('group', NULL, NULL, multiple = TRUE, options = list(
placeholder = 'Select a category',

# predefine all option groups
optgroups = lapply(unique(icd$Description), function(x){
                             list(value = as.character(x), label = as.character(x))
                           }),

# what field to sort according to groupes defined in 'optgroups'
optgroupField = 'Description',

# you can search the data based on these fields
searchField = c('Extended', 'Description', 'Labels'),

# the label that will be shown once value is selected
labelField= 'Extended',

# (each item is a row in data), which requires 'value' column (created by cbind at server side)
render = I("{
           option: function(item, escape) {
           return '<div>' + escape(item.Extended) +'</div>';
            }
          }")
 )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
updateSelectizeInput(session, 'group', choices = cbind(icd, value = 
seq_len(nrow(icd))), server = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This allows several columns to be searched. Below you can see that both name and part of the code is being searched'...

[image]

but it can also be done by only searching the name or the code of the group.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer your original question, but it could be an alternative way to deal with this issue.

You could create two selectInputs. The first is for the group selection which filters the choices of the second selectinput.

[image]

This way you can search for a specific group using first selectInput, and then choose the code from second selectInput.

[image]

This is the Code for it:

```
icd <- tibble::tibble(ICD10=c("C00","C01","C01","C02","C03","C03"), 
              Description=c("Malignant neoplasm of lip","Malignant neoplasm of lip","Malignant neoplasm of base of tongue",
                            "Malignant neoplasm of other and unspecified parts of tongue","Malignant neoplasm of gum","Malignant neoplasm of gum"),
              Extended=c("C00.0","C00.1","C01","C02","C03.0","C03.1"))

icd$Description <- as.factor(as.character(icd$Description))
icd$Extended <- as.factor(as.character(icd$Extended))

cicd <- split(as.list(levels(icd$Extended)), icd$Description)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title="Multiple Select",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(uiOutput("var1_select"),
                 uiOutput("var2_select")),
    mainPanel()
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$var1_select <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      "ind_groupe_select",
      "Select Groups", 
      choices = names(cicd),
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  })
  output$var2_select <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      "ind_var_select",
      "Select Names", 
      choices = cicd[names(cicd) %in% input$ind_groupe_select],
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope this suggestion could be helpful.

Comment: I'm determined to try to make it work with one select input but thank you very much for taking the time to provide an alternative solution. I'm currently looking into either changing the labels of the list and making it searchable that way or  using render in 'selectizeInput'.

Comment: Any suggestions how to make this loop work ? 
  change_label <- function(cicd, icd){
    x <- as.vector(names(cicd))
    for (i in length(x)){
      names(cicd[[x]]) <- x
      return(cicd)
    }
  }
  
  change_label(cicd, icd)

Comment: If you want to change the labels and set them as numbers between 1 and length(x), then you can use this:
change_label <- function(cicd){
  names(cicd) <- seq(length(as.vector(cicd)))
  return(cicd)
}
But if you mean something else please explain more :)

Comment: I've updated the example data. I would like the labels to be the matching 'icd$Labels'. Since my data set is relatively large it needs to be able to run from a loop. "names(cicd[["Malignant neoplasm of lip"]]) <- icd$Labels[icd$Description == "Malignant neoplasm of lip"]"
 On it own it works fine but in the loop it is throwing an error.

Comment: I've managed to add the correct labels, however it seems that the search is done only based on the 'value.labels', which means a choice has to be made between the group name and the specific codes.